# Prevent Submit button appearing on 'new line'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a set of data displayed in rows in a table. At the end of each row is a cell that contains a set of actions that can be performed on that row (View, Print, Edit, Delete, etc.)

Currently I have those actions as simple links that are handled by a controller as GET requests, however I need to change them to POST requests in order to meet best practice.

The current HTML produced by my View is this (shortened for clarity):

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<tr class="row">
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
</tr>
<tr class="row">
    <td>03/10/2014</td>
    <td>
    <a href="/Grid/Details?mainid=123">Details</a> | 
    <a href="/Grid/Print?mainid=123">View</a> | 
    <a href="/Grid/Delete?mainid=123">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

When I replace my delete link with a form, hidden field, and a button the button is placed on a 'new line' regardless of the width of the page. The View uses this code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Grid"))
{
@Html.Hidden("MainID", Model.MainID)
<button type="submit" class="btn-link" style="border-width: 0px; padding: 0px;">Delete</button>
}
```

Which produces this HTML:

```
<a href="/Grid/Details?mainid=123">Details</a> | 
<a href="/Grid/Print?mainid=123">View</a> | 
<form action="/Grid/Delete" method="post">
<input id="MainID" name="MainID" type="hidden" value="123" />
<button type="submit" class="btn-link" style="border-width: 0px; padding: 0px;">Delete</button>
```

Which looks like this:

[image: Bootstrap button on new line]

I tried wrapping the form with a `<div class="form-group">` but that made no difference. Is there a way to make the link styled button stay on the same 'line' as the rest of the links?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `display: inline` to your form style.  `Forms` are block-level elements.

Note: I don't recommend inline styles, but this fixes your issue:

```
<a href="/Grid/Details?mainid=123">Details</a> | 
<a href="/Grid/Print?mainid=123">View</a> | 
<form action="/Grid/Delete" method="post" style="display:inline;">
<input id="MainID" name="MainID" type="hidden" value="123" />
<button type="submit" class="btn-link" style="border-width: 0px; padding: 0px;">Delete</button>
```

Codepen Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPzyKY

Comment: Excellent that does fix it but I'll just give anyone else a chance to come up with a solution that doesn't include inline styles before setting this as the answer.

Comment: I used inline styles simply to illustrate.  Just add a class to your form, and update your stylesheet.  The codepen example shows how to achieve this without inline styles.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `style = "display:inline;"` as object htmlAttributes to your `Html.BeginForm()`.  Forms are block-level elements by default.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Grid"), FormMethod.Post, , new { style = "display:inline;" })
{
      @Html.Hidden("MainID", Model.MainID)
      <button type="submit" class="btn-link" style="border-width: 0px; padding: 0px;">Delete</button>
}
```

The above code will get the all form elements inline.